# How can I Set Index on uneven length rows in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am attempting to set the index of the second dataframe to that of the first dataframe, so that I can reference the rows later by the index that will match across ALL dataframes.

The goal of this is to allow me to reference the original demand dataframe, and subsequent dataframes that have had .rolling(window=X).mean() applied to them all on the same fiscal year/week to perform some calculations.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df_7wkfwdavg.reindex_like(demand_df)

demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df_7wkfwdavg.set_index(demand_df.index)
```

Went into the docs as well in reference to reindex, set_index, reindex_like but either get the new dataframe to start with 201840 with NaN's up until 201846, or get an error says the length does not match between the two dataframe's indexes (which they don't, they would be 57, and 65 give or take)

**LET'S BREAK IT DOWN**

I have two dataframes, the first is demand_df, the second is demand_df_7wkfwdavg.

The first dataframe is setup like this, where the first column is the index, and also indicative of the fiscal year/week, and the second column is the demand values for that particular item (column header is that item name):

```
201840 344.75 
201841 433.75 
201842 344.75 
201843 355.75 
201844 241.60 
201845 241.60 
201846 241.60
```

The second dataframe is setup the same way, but will start at 201846 in this case, after doing the following commands:

```
###Applies a rolling average to each column using the window size specified
demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df.rolling(window=7).mean()


###Fill any NaN's with zeroes
demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df_7wkfwdavg.fillna(0)


###Round the numbers to 2 decimal places
demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df_7wkfwdavg.round(2)


###Remove any row that sums zero
demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df_7wkfwdavg.loc[(demand_df_7wkfwdavg!=0).any(axis=1)]
```

```
201846 314.54 
201847 299.81 
201848 272.36
```

**EXAMPLE OF END STATE GOAL**

Take current week's demand (201840), look across all other dataframes and pull the corresponding values, so in this instance, it would look at the second dataframe and say 201840 = 314.54 for the like item from the first dataframe, instead of 201846 = 314.54.

Desired Output:

```
201840 314.54 
201841 299.81 
201842 272.36
```

Current Output:

```
201846 314.54 
201847 299.81 
201848 272.36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize your problem, it looks like you want the **forward** mean, but it's actually calculating the **trailing** mean. There are some solutions to the index problem (like slicing), but I think a more effective method would be to shift the values when calculating the mean.

If you change:

```
 demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df.rolling(window=7).mean()
```

to

```
 demand_df_7wkfwdavg = demand_df.rolling(window=7).mean().shift(-6)
```

you will get your desired output without adding any steps.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you, just tested and this works exactly as intended. I'll read the docs on the shift, as that's a new one on me. Marking this as the correct answer.